# Always giving me File Not Found Exception Creating file ِin Android

Tags: android, image, filenotfoundexception, outputstream

I am trying to encrypt a photo and save it in the ExternalDirectory as encrypted, but the exception file not found always arises.

Below Two codes I have tried to solve the problem and still gives me the same "File Not Found" message

```
Protected String ScrambledPic(String ImageNow, String key)
{
try{  

        File ImageOld = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ImageNow);
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(ImageOld);       
        Bitmap bm=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        File NewPhoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + File.separator + "picEnc.jpg");
        NewPhoto.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(NewPhoto);
        byte k[]= key.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec KEYY=new SecretKeySpec(k, "DES");
        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEYY);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream,enc);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read=file.read(buffer))!=-1){
            cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        file.close();
        outStream.flush();
        cos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Photo Encrypted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NewImageUri = Uri.fromFile(NewPhoto);
        ImageView scrambled = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scrambled);

        return NewImageUri.toString();

    }

catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return null;
}
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Padding Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Such Algorithm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
}
```

And the other code is:

```
 protected String ScramblePic(String ImageNow, String key)
{
    try {

      File NewPhoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+ "picEnc.jpg");
        NewPhoto.createNewFile();
        File ImageOld = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ImageNow);
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(ImageOld);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(NewPhoto);
        Bitmap bm=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte k[]= key.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec KEYY=new SecretKeySpec(k, "DES");
        Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEYY);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(outStream,enc);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read=file.read(buffer))!=-1){
            cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        file.close();
        outStream.flush();
        cos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Photo Encrypted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NewImageUri = Uri.fromFile(NewPhoto);
        ImageView scrambled = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scrambled);

        return NewImageUri.toString();

    }

catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return null;
 }
    catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Padding Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Such Algorithm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }
    catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return ImageNow;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Why don't you create a new Hello World Java app, and just focus on the file opening to ensure you're getting it right. 

Have you printed the String represented by return value from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to verify that it is the right directory?  And if you try to simply create a new file is it created and in the right location?   Have you tried taking it incrementally and building a smaller prototype of the failure in a separate Hello World program to isolate the problem and validate method calls?

Comment: I'm not sure which lines, and my "logcat" is not working...
I have reviewed all of the possible ways to write on a file and I still have this problem here...
Please if you have a solution help me..

Comment: add ImageOld.exists() just after the first line if it does not exist, then print out the paths to see if you passing the correct path, and return.